# Unity rewarded video ads

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityads

Once the user has finished watching the rewarded video ad, I want to give the user 3 additional lives and let the user continue the game from where the player died along with the same score.

I have been able to add the extra lives code but am not able to get the same score.

This is the score script:

```
public int playerScore = 0; 

if (!isDead && collision.tag == "ScoreChecker") {
        gameManager.AddToScore();
    }

public void AddToScore()
{
    playerScore++;
    if (playerScore > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore",0))
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", playerScore);
        Debug.Log("Highscore");
    }

    Debug.Log("player score" + playerScore);
}
```

This is the extra lives reward script:

```
public void ReceiveReward()
 {
    totalLives = 3;
    UIManager.instance.UpdateLivesIcons();        
    UIManager.instance.RewardPanel.SetActive(false);
 }
```

I have been able to reward the extra lives, but not sure how to let the user continue with the same score when the player died.

Comment: What about the death script? Does the game continue playing correctly just the score resets to 0 or what happens?

Comment: @ThomasByy, once the player dies, the score resets to 0. This works as required.....its just the I was not able to get the score once the player has watched a video add...I will try the solution given by syed...

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as I have understood your question you are facing difficulty in saving score at the point your player died and then revived back you want to continue.

```
private savedScore = 0;
//Call this function when your player dies.
public void SaveScoreBeforeDeath()
{
    savedScore = playerScore
}
//get your saved score and assign it.
public void ReceiveReward()
 {
    totalLives = 3;
    playerScore = savedScore;
    UIManager.instance.UpdateLivesIcons();        
    UIManager.instance.RewardPanel.SetActive(false);
 }
```